# How to get selected element in debugger in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, javascript-debugger

Say I click on an element in the debug panel:

[image]

I can access the currently selected element using `$0` in the debugger console.

However, what I would like to do is, in a chrome extension, listen for when I click on an element *in the debugger*. So when I click the element in the DOM tree in the debugger, I get notified in some event in the chrome extension.

Wondering how to do that. I would like to have access to it either in the background.js script or the content.js script.

Comment: @hindmost I have seen [react do something close to it](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en) I think, but not sure if it accomplishes this specifically.

Comment: See [Chrome DevTools extension: how to get selected element from elements panel in content script?](//stackoverflow.com/q/17214171) and google for "ElementsPanel onSelectionChanged.addListener"

Comment: Here's a better way than using $0. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/accessibility/focus